# Как сделать поля резиновыми и одинаковой ширины?

Tags: css

Есть форма. Сейчас Поля формы резиновые, и изменяют размер при изменении ширины окна. Но проблема в том, что ширина блока `.input_block` = (100% - 40px)/2. Из-за этого у нас ширина полей разная. Как сделать одинаковую ширину полей, оставив ширину label (она разная и левых и правых полей)?

Блок `.input_block` должен остаться. Из-за него и не могу понять, как сделать. Если бы его не было, то ширину поля можно было бы легко вычислить (от ширины формы отнять ширину правого и левого label и разделить на 2).

```css
form {
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

form .input_block {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
  width: calc((100% - 60px)/2);
}

form .input_block:nth-child(2n) {
 margin: 0 0 20px 40px;
}

form .input_block:last-child {
 margin: 0 0 0 40px;
}

form label {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 20px;
 letter-spacing: normal;
}

form .input_block:nth-child(2n-1) label {
 width: 63px;
}

form .input_block:nth-child(2n) label {
 width: 77px;
}

form input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}

form .input_block:nth-child(2n-1) input {
    width: calc(100% - 63px);
}

form .input_block:nth-child(2n) input {
    width: calc(100% - 77px);
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="php">
    
    <div class="input_block">
        <label>Имя: </label>
        <input type="text" name="login">
    </div>
    
    <div class="input_block">
        <label>Фамилия: </label>
        <input type="text" name="password">
    </div>
    
    <div class="input_block">
        <label>E-mail: </label>
        <input type="text" name="login">
    </div>
    
    <div class="input_block">
        <label>Телефон: </label>
        <input type="text" name="password">
    </div>
    
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Нужно скорректировать ширину `.input_block` на разницу в ширине `label`:

```css
form {
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

form .input_block {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

form .input_block:nth-child(2n-1) {
  width: calc((100% - 54px)/2);
}

form .input_block:nth-child(2n) {
  margin: 0 0 20px 40px;
  width: calc((100% - 26px)/2);
}

form .input_block:last-child {
  margin: 0 0 0 40px;
}

form label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  letter-spacing: normal;
}

form .input_block:nth-child(2n-1) label {
  width: 63px;
}

form .input_block:nth-child(2n) label {
  width: 77px;
}

form input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

form .input_block:nth-child(2n-1) input {
    width: calc(100% - 63px);
}

form .input_block:nth-child(2n) input {
    width: calc(100% - 77px);
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="php">
    <div class="input_block">
        <label>Имя: </label>
        <input type="text" name="login">
        <label>Фамилия: </label>
        <input type="text" name="password">
    </div>
    <div class="input_block">
        <label>E-mail: </label>
        <input type="text" name="login">
        <label>Телефон: </label>
        <input type="text" name="password">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
form{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    border-spacing:4px 0;
}
form .input_block{
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
}
form .input_block label,
form .input_block label input{
    display:table-cell;
}
form .input_block label{
    min-width:49px;
    max-width:68px;
    width:88px;
}
form .input_block input{
    width:100%;
    min-width:73px;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="php">
    <div class="input_block">
        <label>Имя: </label>
        <input type="text" name="login">
        <label>Фамилия: </label>
        <input type="text" name="password">
    </div>
    <div class="input_block">
        <label>E-mail: </label>
        <input type="text" name="login">
        <label>Телефон: </label>
        <input type="text" name="password">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Ваш вариант не подходит. В вопросе я написал. что ширина label должна сохраниться. И отступа у вас нет.